# Update in pandas on specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I want to update values in one `pandas` data frame based on the values in another dataframe, but I want to specify which column to update by (i.e., which column should be the “key” for looking up matching rows). Right now it seems to do treat the first column as the key one. Is there a way to pass it a specific column name?

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_a = pd.DataFrame()
df_a['x'] = range(5)
df_a['y'] = range(4, -1, -1)
df_a['z'] = np.random.rand(5)

df_b = pd.DataFrame()
df_b['x'] = range(5)
df_b['y'] = range(5)
df_b['z'] = range(5)


print('df_b:')
print(df_b.head())
print('\nold df_a:')
print(df_a.head(10))

df_a.update(df_b)

print('\nnew df_a:')
print(df_a.head())
```

Out:

```
df_b:
   x  y  z
0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4

old df_a:
   x  y         z
0  0  4  0.333648
1  1  3  0.683656
2  2  2  0.605688
3  3  1  0.816556
4  4  0  0.360798

new df_a:
   x  y  z
0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1
2  2  2  2
3  3  3  3
4  4  4  4
```

You see, what it did is replaced `y` and `z` in `df_a` with the respective columns in `df_b` based on matches of `x` between `df_a` and `df_b`.

What if I wanted to keep `y` the same? What if I want it to replace based on `y` and not `x`. Also, what if there are multiple columns on which I’d like to do the replacement (in the real problem, I have to update a dataset with a new dataset, where there is a match in two or three columns between the two on the values from a fourth column).

Basically, I want to do some sort of a merge-replace action, where I specify which columns I am merging/replacing `on` and which column should be replaced.

Hope this makes things clearer. If this cannot be accomplished with `update` in `pandas`, I am wondering if there is another way (short of writing a separate function with `for` loops for it).

Comment: Come on dude, if someone who had no idea what you were doing looked at this do you suppose they would have enough info to be able to help?

Comment: Added sample code and output.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution, but it seems somewhat inelegant:

```
df_merge = df_a.merge(df_b, on='y', how='left', suffixes=('_a', '_b'))
print(df_merge.head())

df_merge['x'] = df_merge.x_b
df_merge['z'] = df_merge.z_b

df_update = df_a.copy()
df_update.update(df_merge)
print(df_update)
```

Out:

```
   x_a  y       z_a  x_b  z_b
0    0  0  0.505949    0    0
1    1  1  0.231265    1    1
2    2  2  0.241109    2    2
3    3  3  0.579765  NaN  NaN
4    4  4  0.172409  NaN  NaN
   x  y         z
0  0  0  0.000000
1  1  1  1.000000
2  2  2  2.000000
3  3  3  0.579765
4  4  4  0.172409
5  5  5  0.893562
6  6  6  0.638034
7  7  7  0.940911
8  8  8  0.998453
9  9  9  0.965866
```